# Libraries not found when using PyPy

Tags: python

I'm trying to use PyPy with some python code I'm write as it's a TON faster but I have having trouble getting it to load the library [spidev](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spidev/2.0)

Are some libraries just not compatible with PyPy or do I need to update it's search path or something?

Comment: The version of Python you are using may be relevant.  Some modules work with Python <3 but not Python 3.

Comment: But PyPy is supposed to be 2.7.3 compatible... not 3. And that's the version of python I am using and spidev works fine.

Comment: Do you have any other relevant information?  Code?  Error messages?

Comment: Just "ImportError: No module named spidev" as if it weren't installed. Which it is because it works the the CPython interpreter

Answer (score 1):

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=50674 suggests that non-Python modules such as spidev (coded in C I guess) may not work with Py Py.